# How to specify specific port number for WCF service hosted in IIS 7 over NetTcpBinding?

Tags: .net, wcf, iis

I really have two questions.

1. When hosting a WCF service in IIS 7 over the NetTcpBinding I am unable to make the service respect the base address port number I specify for the endpoint (eg. net.tcp://ServerName:9000/Services/). If I understand correctly, IIS provides it's own base addresses and does not respect base addresses configured in the host section of the config file. If this is true, is there a way to configure specific ports for services delivered over the NetTcpBinding when hosted in IIS 7?
2. When creating a website other than the default website IIS 7 requires a different HTTP port number (ex. 81) to access the site. After configuring the site to host services delivered over NetTcpBinding I am unable to add reference to the endpoints. Is it possible to create additional websites (other than the default website) using different port numbers for HTTP and expose service endpoints over the NetTcpBinding?

Comment: take a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms788757.aspx note the tool appcmd.exe

Comment: Yes, I have enabled non Http protocols in IIS. This is possible in the UI without using appcmd. It allows you to modify the "binding information" but not the actual port number (although the port number is specified in the binding section, it does not affect the actual port used). Only HTTP and HTTPS allow the port number to be changed.

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/santhoshonline/archive/2010/07/01/howto-nettcpbinding-on-iis-and-things-to-remember.aspx hope it helps